# Where to clean up unmanaged resource in dispose pattern?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'm confused about this pattern.

If disposing is true(called from Dispose()) we free managed objects there.
If disposing is false(called from Finalizer()) it is not safe to access referenced object, these referenced objects are the unmanaged objects like filestream.

If disposing is true then we won't be able to free unmanaged objects?
If disposing is false we won't be able to free managed objects?

Searching this pattern, there has different implementation in Dispose(boolean) method. [MSDN implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)

And this one I got from examples and tutorials.

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Free any other managed objects here.
            }
            else
            {
                //not safe to access referenced object
            }
            // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        }
        disposed = true;
    }
```

Comment: `// Free any unmanaged objects here.` "executes" whether or not `disposing` is true. Look at the control flow again.

Comment: *... unmanaged objects like filestream*. A `FileStream` is a **managed object**, the underlying file handle would be the unmanaged one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In properly formed `IDisposable` pattern `true` value of `disposing` implies that we reached the method from the explicit `Dispose` call or by leaving `using` scope which is preferable way of `IDisposable` consumption. However not all consumers are properly implemented and in order to ensure that we are able to reclaim all unmanaged resources in the `IDisposable` implementation we call `Dispose(false)` from the finalizer. So `false` in the `Dispose` indicates that we reached this call at the finalization phase and some references can be unavailable at this stage that's why we use this flag - to distinguish what we can do under normal flow execution and what we can do under the finalization stage conditions. Unmanaged resources we deallocate regardless of this flag.

Answer (score 1):

the clean up of unmanged resources must be done inside the method `Dispose(boolean disposing)` regardless of the value of the parameter `disposing`. You can find [more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose)